# Kendo-Ui angular 2 grid control with check boxes

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI GRiD in angular2 . it is not maintaining checkbox checked state on page change event. My angular2 runs in the typescript scriptings

Answer (score 0):

Try to set    `persistSelection: true`    in your grid options